# Convergence to a norm

Tags: central-limit-theorem, brownian-motion, norm

Let $x$ be a $d$-dimensional real valued vector. It holds

$x^{T}A B^{1/2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\lfloor ns\rfloor}\epsilon_{t}\to \|x\|_{ABA} W(s)$ for $s\in[0,1]$ with $\epsilon_{t}$ iid with mean zero and variance one,  $W(s)$ being a $d$-dim standard Wiener Process and $A$ and $B$ being $d\times d$ matrices with $A$ being symmetric and positive semi-definite and $\|x\|_{ABA}=\sqrt{x^{T}ABAx}$. The part with the sum and the Wiener Process follows from FCLT. But what about the part with the norm? Why does this hold true?

Edit: I think in $\|x\|_{ABA} W(s)$ the process $W(s)$ should be a 1-dim Wiener Process instead of a d-dimensional. But without the $x^{T}A B^{1/2}$ before the sum it should be a d-dimensional Process, because the $\epsilon_{t}$ are d-dim RV (FCLT). So why and how do we get a change in the dimension of the Wiener Process?

Comment: Not sure, but the norm part looks sort of like a scaling of a random variable so that it has unit variance $\sigma^{-1}X \rightarrow Z,$ $Z\sim N(0,1),$ while $X\rightarrow Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)?$

Comment: Yeah. If you think of B as the Covariance Matrix of the RV $\epsilon$ if they have this specific covariance matrix instead of variance 1

Comment: I edited the root for the norm.